# How to Authorise whatsapp in iOS App?

Tags: ios, swift, api, messaging, whatsapp

I want to authorise my iOS application to send messages through whatsapp (without opening the whatsapp app). I think user will give authorisation to my app to use whatsapp, or to login to whatsapp though my app to grant authorisation.
My question is, is this possible? And if yes, how this can be done?

Comment: Take a look at `UIActivityViewController`

Answer (score 0):

`UIActivityviewcontroller` is the option but for sending message you need to open the whatsapp app .

Comment: Do you know how can I send a message without opening the whatsapp app?